# Fast way to count distinct column values (using an index?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

## The problem: query taking too long

I have a new table that looks like this, with 3e6 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE everything_crowberry (
    id             SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id       INTEGER,
    group_type     group_type_name,
    epub_id        TEXT,
    reg_user_id    INTEGER,
    device_id      TEXT,
    campaign_id    INTEGER,
    category_name  TEXT,
    instance_name  TEXT,
    protobuf       TEXT,
    UNIQUE (group_id, group_type, reg_user_id, category_name, instance_name)
);
```

This generally makes sense for my context, and most queries are acceptably fast.

But what's not fast are queries like this:

```
analytics_staging=> explain analyze select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=392177.29..392177.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=8909.698..8909.699 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=0.00..384180.83 rows=3198583 width=4) (actual time=0.461..6347.272 rows=3198583 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.063 ms
 Execution time: 8909.730 ms
(4 rows)

Time: 8910.110 ms
analytics_staging=> select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry;
 count 
-------
   481

Time: 8736.364 ms
```

I did create an index on `group_id`, but while that index is used on a WHERE clause, it is not being used in the above.  So I conclude I've misunderstood something about how postgres uses indices.  Note (query result) that there are under 500 distinct group_id's.

```
CREATE INDEX everything_crowberry_group_id ON everything_crowberry(group_id);
```

Any pointers what I've misunderstood or how to make this particular query go faster?

## Updates

To help with questions posed in the comments, I've added the suggested changes here. For future readers, I've included the detail to better understand how this gets debugged.

I notice in playing about that most of the time is taken up in the initial aggregate.

### seqscan

Turning off seqscan makes this much worse:

```
analytics_staging=> set enable_seqscan = false;

analytics_staging=> explain analyze select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=444062.28..444062.29 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=38927.323..38927.323 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=51884.99..436065.82 rows=3198583 width=4) (actual time=458.252..36167.789 rows=3198583 loops=1)
         Heap Blocks: exact=35734 lossy=316446
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on everything_crowberry_group  (cost=0.00..51085.35 rows=3198583 width=0) (actual time=448.537..448.537 rows=3198583 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.064 ms
 Execution time: 38927.971 ms

Time: 38930.328 ms
```

### WHERE can make it worse

Restricting to a very small set of group id's makes it even worse, whereas I might have thought it would be easier to count a smaller set of things.

```
analytics_staging=> explain analyze select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry WHERE group_id > 380;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=385954.43..385954.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=13438.422..13438.422 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=18742.95..383451.68 rows=1001099 width=4) (actual time=132.571..12673.233 rows=986572 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (group_id > 380)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 70816
         Heap Blocks: exact=49632 lossy=79167
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on everything_crowberry_group  (cost=0.00..18492.67 rows=1001099 width=0) (actual time=120.816..120.816 rows=986572 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (group_id > 380)
 Planning time: 1.294 ms
 Execution time: 13439.017 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 13442.603 ms
```

### explain(analyze, buffers)

```
analytics_staging=> explain(analyze, buffers) select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=392177.29..392177.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=7329.775..7329.775 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16283 read=335912, temp read=4693 written=4693
   ->  Seq Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=0.00..384180.83 rows=3198583 width=4) (actual time=0.224..4615.015 rows=3198583 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=16283 read=335912
 Planning time: 0.089 ms
 Execution time: 7329.818 ms

Time: 7331.084 ms
```

### work_mem is too small (cf. explain(analyze, buffers) above)

Increasing it from the default 4 MB to 10 MB provides a bit of improvement, from 7300 ms to 5500 ms or so.

### Changing SQL helps a bit, too.

```
analytics_staging=> EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) SELECT group_id FROM everything_crowberry GROUP BY group_id;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=392177.29..392181.56 rows=427 width=4) (actual time=4686.525..4686.612 rows=481 loops=1)
   Group Key: group_id
   Buffers: shared hit=96 read=352099
   ->  Seq Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=0.00..384180.83 rows=3198583 width=4) (actual time=0.034..4017.122 rows=3198583 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=96 read=352099
 Planning time: 0.094 ms
 Execution time: 4686.686 ms

Time: 4687.461 ms

analytics_staging=> EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) SELECT distinct group_id FROM everything_crowberry;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=392177.29..392181.56 rows=427 width=4) (actual time=5536.151..5536.262 rows=481 loops=1)
   Group Key: group_id
   Buffers: shared hit=128 read=352067
   ->  Seq Scan on everything_crowberry  (cost=0.00..384180.83 rows=3198583 width=4) (actual time=0.030..4946.024 rows=3198583 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=128 read=352067
 Planning time: 0.074 ms
 Execution time: 5536.321 ms

Time: 5537.380 ms

analytics_staging=> SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM everything_crowberry GROUP BY group_id) ec;
 count 
-------
   481

Time: 4927.671 ms
```

### Creating a view is a major win, but maybe creates performance issues elsewhere.

```
analytics_production=> CREATE VIEW everything_crowberry_group_view AS select distinct group_id, group_type FROM everything_crowberry;
CREATE VIEW
analytics_production=> EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) SELECT distinct group_id FROM everything_crowberry_group_view;
                                                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=0.56..357898.89 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.046..1976.882 rows=447 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=667230 read=109291 dirtied=108 written=988
   ->  Subquery Scan on everything_crowberry_group_view  (cost=0.56..357897.19 rows=680 width=4) (actual time=0.046..1976.616 rows=475 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=667230 read=109291 dirtied=108 written=988
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..357890.39 rows=680 width=8) (actual time=0.044..1976.378 rows=475 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=667230 read=109291 dirtied=108 written=988
               ->  Index Only Scan using everything_crowberry_group_id_group_type_reg_user_id_catego_key on everything_crowberry  (cost=0.56..343330.63 rows=2911953 width=8) (actual time=0.043..1656.409 rows=2912005 loops=1)
                     Heap Fetches: 290488
                     Buffers: shared hit=667230 read=109291 dirtied=108 written=988
 Planning time: 1.842 ms
 Execution time: 1977.086 ms
```

Comment: Can you run an `explain (analyze, buffers)` instead of just `explain (analyze)`? Maybe use `set track_io_timing=on` before that, so that we can see the I/IO timings as well

Comment: Done, question updated.  I see now that the bulk of the time is taking place in the aggregate, not the seqscan, so the usage or not of an index is perhaps a red herring.

Comment: "*temp read=4693 written=4693*" indicates that there isn't enough `work_mem` to do the aggregation in memory.

Comment: What is your Postgres version? I would have expected a Parallel Seq Scan and a Parallel Hash Aggregate for that size of the table

Comment: Version is 9.5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198141/discussion-between-jma-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For relatively ***few* distinct values in `group_id`** (many rows per group) - as seems to be your case:

> 3e6 rows / under 500 distinct group_id's

To make this ***fast***, you would need an *index skip scan* (a.k.a. *loose index scan*). That's not implemented up to Postgres 12. But you can work around the limitation with a recursive query:

Replace:

```
select count(distinct group_id) from everything_crowberry;
```

With:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (SELECT group_id FROM everything_crowberry ORDER BY group_id LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT group_id FROM everything_crowberry
           WHERE  group_id > t.group_id ORDER BY group_id LIMIT 1)
   FROM   cte t
   WHERE  t.group_id IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT count(group_id) FROM cte;
```

I use `count(group_id)` instead of the slightly faster `count(*)` to conveniently eliminate a `NULL` value from the final recursion - as `count(<expression>)` only counts nonnull values.

Also, does not matter whether `group_id` can be `NULL`, as that's not counted by your query anyway.

Can use the index you already have:

```
CREATE INDEX everything_crowberry_group_id ON everything_crowberry(group_id);
```

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

For relatively ***many* distinct values in `group_id`** (few rows per group) - or for small tables - plain `DISTINCT` will be faster. Typically fastest when done in a subquery, as opposed to an added clause to the `count()`:

```
SELECT count(group_id) -- or just count(*) to include possible NULL value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM everything_crowberry) sub;
```

Comment: good explanation and neat solution!  I edited the query slightly to remove a reference to `col` that I assume was left over from editing

Comment: Wow, that's really fast!  Thanks!

Comment: Should be several order of magnitude for your case. Oh, and for the query at hand it does not matter whether `group_id` can be NULL. (For other queries it might.)

Comment: Yes, it's 6 ms.

Comment: group_id is not NULL (the constraint was missing when the table was created, I should fix that), but it matters enormously whether I have that `WHERE t.group_id IS NOT NULL` in the query.

Comment: @jma: The `WHERE  t.group_id IS NOT NULL` in my rCTE is actually unrelated to NULL values in the table (though it deceivingly looks like that on a first glance). It's the break condition that stops the recursion after the correlated subquery has found no next greater `group_id`, which results in a NULL value in `t.group_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues with `count(distinct)` in Postgres at times.

How does this work?

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct group_id
      from everything_crowberry
     ) ec;
```

Or:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct on (group_id) ec.*
      from everything_crowberry
     ) ec;
```

Note that the `NULL` handling is slightly difference, but the queries can easily be adjusted for that.

Comment: Nice suggestion!  With work_mem increased a bit (thanks @a_horse_with_no_name) the query takes 6000 ms.  Your first suggestion is 4600 ms.  My GROUP BY (above) is 4900.  Creating a VIEW is 2000.